# Android store data in a server

Tags: java, android, save

I am developing an Android application in which I developed the registration page in which the users details are collected... username, password, mobilenumber etc.. now the details are stored in database in the android application itself... But I need to store this data in a webserver.. when user give all details the data has to be saved in a server... what I have to do for that ... is there any free web server available.. for me to test ... I am giving the code that I developed ..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 

{


     Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
        btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);




        if(loginDataBaseAdapter.getUsercount() >= 3)

        {
            btnSignUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }



        else
        {





        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);

                   }


        });
    }


    }


    public void signIn(View V)
    {
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
         dialog.setTitle("Login");

         // get the References of views
         final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
         final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
         final  EditText editTextMobileNumber = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


         Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);


         btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String mobileNumber = editTextMobileNumber.getText().toString();

                // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);



                String sd = getIntent().getStringExtra("number"); 




                // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                if(password.equals(storedPassword) && (mobileNumber.equals(sd))) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


         dialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
         {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close The Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy before the server you will need web service to store data onto the server database which mostly written PHP. Then after there are several free testing servers available just google it

Good luck..

Answer (score 1):

I think **Wamp server** is best option to play with server related utilities.You can use it it even if you are offline. and it provides various option for data storage. It Mainly uses **MySql and PHP** scripts for fast performance.

For more information Have a look at,

[Installing and testing Wamp server](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html)